# GtkTextView size

Tags: gtktextview

How do I set the size of GtKTextView? I think I can't use gtk_widget_set_usize.

Comment: Why do you think you can't use gtk_widget_set_usize?

Comment: Sorry, I received an error at compile phase, but now it works! However gtk_widget_set_usize has been deprecated, so I used gtk_widget_set_size_request.
For the maximum length?

Answer (score 4):

You cannot control size of a widget directly, instead this is done by its container.  You can force a minimum size by using `gtk_widget_set_size_request()`, it will be respected by all standard containers.  There is no similar way to set maximum size in the same way, this totally depends on the container.